# React: Change 'background-position' based on API endpoint value?

Tags: mongodb, api, reactjs, react-router

I have an API endpoint that looks like this:

```
{ "backgroundPos" : "center" }
```

Each logged in user will have this endpoint and its value associated with their account. What I'm trying to figure out is how to insert backgroundPos's value into `<div>`, something like this:

```
React.createClass({
        var divStyle = {
            backgroundPos: 'center'
        }

        return (
            <li>
                <div style="background-position: {divStyle}></div>
            </li>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html):

> In React, inline styles are not specified as a string. Instead they are specified with an object whose key is the camelCased version of the style name, and whose value is the style's value, usually a string.

So to set the background position you'd do:

`<div style={{ backgroundPosition: divStyle.backgroundPos }} />`

Comment: How do I write a function to get the values from the API? I'm not sure how to get the value that's in the database.